# Python figuring out the maximum number?

Tags: python

Write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user enters 'done'. Once 'done' is entered, print out the largest and smallest of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a valid number catch it with a try/except and put out an appropriate message and ignore the number.

I have this so far but im confused on how to create a way to compare the maximum value?  Im new to programming and im just asking for help.  Also do I include the try and except block before the while with the try? and then error for the except?

```
 largest = None
 smallest = None
 while True:
     num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
     if num == "done" : break
       print num

 print "Maximum", largest
```

Comment: Store the numbers in a list, lists have `min()` and `max()` methods.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: There is no need to store *all* of the user input.

Answer (score 5):

```
nums = []
while True:
  n = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
  if n == "done":
    break
  try:
    nums.append(int(n))
  except ValueError:
    print "Invalid input"

print "Min: %d" % min(nums)
print "Max: %d" % max(nums)
```

Comment: -1 OP is obviously new to python. This can be solved using his code, without additional concepts (no `list`, no `min()`, no `max()`).

Answer (score 3):

```
largest = None
smallest = None
first_number = True

while True:
    num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" : break

    try:
        num = int(num)
        if first_number:
            largest = num
            smallest = num
            first_number = False
        else:
            largest = max(largest, num)
            smallest = min(smallest, num)
    except Exception, e:
        print "Not Valid Input!!!"
        continue

print "Maximum", largest
print "Minimum", smallest
```

Comment: Thanks! Makes tons of sense!

Comment: -1 That `first_number` variable is not necessary. The `try` is also massive, when it should be 1-line long. I don't think this is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers =[]
while True:
     num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
     if num == "done" :
         break
     else:
         numbers.append(num)

print max(numbers)
print min(numbers)
```

So, the logic is to add the numbers to a list and use functions max and min. You can write code to handle exceptions yourself.

Comment: And what happens when the user inputs a non numeric string?

Comment: On py3x this will raise error, and in py2x you'll get weird results.

Comment: On Python 2.x I think it'll sort by ascii value of the first character of each string. And then the second in case of a tie, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
largest =  None
smallest = None

while True:
   num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
   if num == "done": break
   if len(num) < 1 : break
   try:
    num=int(num)
   except:
    print "Invalid input"
    continue
    if num is smallest:
      smallest = num
    if num > largest:
      largest = num
print "Maximum is ", largest
print "Minimum is ", smallest
```

Comment: It's great of you to contribute, but please be a little more attentive to detail. I won't downvote, but the code is badly indented, hard to read due to lack of white lines, misuses `is` when `==` would be appropriate in a line where neither makes sense, has faulty logic and is vulnerable to input errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a very small modification of your original program: just keep tabs of the smallest and largest numbers as you consider them.

```
largest  = None
smallest = None

while True:
    string = raw_input("Enter a number: ")

    if string == "done":
        break

    try:
        num = int(string)
    except ValueError:
        print "Not a number"
        continue

    if largest is None or num > largest:
        largest = num

    if smallest is None or num < smallest:
        smallest = num
```

Answer (score 0):

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
num = raw_input('Enter a number: ')

if num == 'done':
    print 'Maximum is %s' % largest
    print 'Minimum is %s' % smallest
    break

try:
    num = int(num)

    if smallest is None or num <= smallest:
        smallest = num

    if largest is None or num >= largest:
        largest = num

except:
    print 'Invalid input'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also a python beginning learner, this question I have noticed in 'Python for Everyone' by Charles Russell Severance. My answer is below.

```
prompt = 'Enter the number: '
initial_value = 0.0
while True:
    thing = input(prompt)
    if thing == 'done':
        break
    try:
        num = float(thing)
    except:
        print('Invalid input')
        continue
    num = float(thing)
    if num > initial_value:
        max = num
        min = initial_value
    else:
        min = num
print('Max', max)
print('Min', min)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
maximum = None
minimum = None
total = 0
count = 0

while True:
    try:
        num = input('Enter a number: ')
        if num != 'done':
            num = int(num)
            total += num
            count += 1
        else:
            break
        if maximum is None and minimum is None:
            maximum = num
            minimum = num
        if num > maximum:
            maximum = num
        if num < minimum:
            minimum = num
    except:
        print('Invalid input')

print(total, count, 'Maximum:', maximum, 'Minimum:', minimum)
```

Answer (score -1):

By assigning `num` to a single value, you are overwriting it through every iteration of the loop. Use a list instead.

```
num = []
finish = "n"
while finish.lower() == "n"
    try:
        num.append(int(raw_input("Enter a number: ")))
    except ValueError:
         print "Not a number"
    finish = raw_input("Would you like to add another number? (y/n): ")

print max(num)
```

Comment: -1 this will max on alphabetical order, possibly giving weird results

Comment: Yeah I edited it as soon as I hit submit, but you had already downvoted. Take care

Comment: I don't see any edit making this code work. At a minimum you;d need to use numa.append(int(raw_input(...))) - you could use float instead of int. Also a try/except to handle the exceptions from bad data.

Comment: What? Have you refreshed your page in the last 10 minutes? That's exactly what my code says...